# Why can't I access tomcat webpage from docker?

Tags: docker, tomcat

```
e27402dee2b9   tc_img    "catalina.sh run"   5 minutes ago   Up 29 seconds   8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   tc_cont
```

I am running tomcat latest image in docker. Docker has no OS image. Just the tomcat image. I run docker in CentOS. I have the above container running when I executed `docker ps` but I cannot load tomcat page when I try to access http://localhost:8081 from web browser. is there anything I do need to do further to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It will return a 404 since there are no webapps loaded by default.

You need to create a dockerfile like below and add a sample webpage.

FROM tomcat:9.0
ADD sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [“catalina.sh”, “run”]